# Is this a typo in C++ Primer Plus (Sixth Edition)

Tags: c++, lambda

In the book C++ Primer Plus I see the following example:

```
auto mod3 = [](int x){return x % 3 == 0; }  //<---- note no semicolon
conut1 = std::count_if(n1.begin(), n1.end(), mod3);
```

In my own code I just tried to use it in the following way:

```
auto compareEntry = [](PCEntry* a, PCEntry* b) { return (a->getSize() < b->getSize());  }; //<--- semicolon
std::priority_queue< PCEntry*, std::vector<PCEntry*>, decltype(compareEntry) > sorted(compareEntry);
```

I had problems with this code until I added the semicolon after lambda following a post on stack overflow.

My question:

Is it an error in the book? Or Am I missing something.
It looks inconsistent to me.

Just in case:
Book: C++ Primer Plus (Sixth Edition) S. Prata page: 1189

Comment: It is a typo in the book.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the book.  There should be a `;` at the end there.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the semicolon is needed and the compiler will show an error, something like "syntax error: missing ';'...".